# WebApi Data Connection

Tags: sql, sql-server, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

Hi I am new in writing Web Api, and today I want to set up a webAPI and have my AngularJS app to connect to it.

I was able to create to create the webAPI by creating new project in Visual Studio 2013, however I can see that no connections appear under **Data Connection**, do any of you know what I need to do so database connection appears here, including the API default tables?? Such as user account table and so on?

[image]

Thank you.

***** Updated ******

When I click on **Add New Connection** as @Bob requested I get a popup which has no values under server (so dropdown isn't populated), so not very sure what to add in there. Also do you think I need to install some SQL in my machine or similar? From my understanding the db should have been created as soon as I created the project, also this is what I have noticed on other tutorials.

[image]

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

click on the black circle I drew on your picutre and follow the prompts should be easy.

Comment: Thank you, but I already tried this and for some reason the dropdown for servers isn't populated, so no options there at all. The project should have created a db for it from my understanding, so you think I need to install anything in my machine?

Comment: Make sure you are on the same domain as your databases are and also you can try hitting refresh to get a link to try to get the database to show up. I am not sure anything else would need to be done in order for the databases to show up. You can also try changing the data source if your database is not microsoft sql server as seen in your screenshot.

Comment: So I am just using localhost domain and nothing happens when I click refresh, however I was able to attach a database created externally, but I really want the asp.net user tables and other tables which were suppose to be created automatically. It is very frustrating that it didn't create me a database.